# DMV sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats - duplicate entries

Tags: trigger, sql-server-2019, dmv

I am running following select:

```
SELECT tstats.object_id, tstats.database_id, tstats.sql_handle, 
DB_NAME(tstats.database_id) AS [db_name], OBJECT_NAME(tstats.object_id) AS      
trigger_name, tstats.execution_count, tstats.total_worker_time,     
tstats.total_logical_reads, tstats.total_logical_writes, OBJECT_NAME(trgs.parent_id) AS  
trigger_parent, getdate() AS [timestamp] FROM sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats tstats INNER 
JOIN  sys.triggers trgs ON tstats.object_id = trgs.object_id ORDER BY object_id asc
```

SQL server version is 2019 (RTM-CU24) Standard.

The problem is, that some of the triggers are returned twice (same object ID, different execution count and other stats):

[image: Duplicate trigger stats]

I am trying to sample this `sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats` DMV and make deltas per minute to see which triggers are killing the application performance - I thought the combination of database name, trigger's parent name and trigger name (or object_id) are unique. They are returned multiple times with different runtime stats which I can't understand. Hints appreciated.

Comment: Multiple plans suggest the cache keys are different (different SET options). Add `OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(tstats.plan_handle) AS epa` to the query to view the attribute and value for the cache key.

Comment: @DanGuzman - you hit a nail on the head - for one trigger (actually two rows with different execution counts) I see difference in SET options like FREE_CURSORS, FREE_EXEC_CONTEXT etc - these have differenet values. Would it be safe, for my cause, to SUM the rows for the same trigger and omit different SET options or there's another gotcha? Thanks.

Comment: Might be interesting to keep the distinction so that you can see things like the top plan having much higher aggregate reads despite a much lower execution count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple cache entries will exist for the same trigger when the cache key is different, commonly due to different session `SET` options. This version of your query returns the cache key attribute/value pairs for each plan in a single column.

```
SELECT
      tstats.object_id
    , tstats.database_id
    , tstats.sql_handle
    , DB_NAME(tstats.database_id) AS [db_name]
    , OBJECT_NAME(tstats.object_id) AS trigger_name
    , tstats.execution_count
    , tstats.total_worker_time
    , tstats.total_logical_reads
    , tstats.total_logical_writes
    , OBJECT_NAME(trgs.parent_id) AS trigger_parent
    , getdate() AS [timestamp]
    , (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(epa.attribute, '=', CAST(value AS nvarchar(100))), ',') FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(tstats.plan_handle) AS epa WHERE epa.is_cache_key = 1) AS CacheKeyValues
FROM sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats tstats 
INNER JOIN  sys.triggers trgs ON tstats.object_id = trgs.object_id 
ORDER BY object_id asc;
```

You could aggregate rows for the same trigger to avoid dups, which might be good enough for your purpose, but be aware this might not tell the complete story since each plan was compiled independently and could be different.